# Keynote - Print Slide with Notes

Tags: keynote

I know there is a way in Keynote to print your slides with notes. However, on some of my slides I have notes that are VERY long (as in a couple of pages). I'd like to print these off as handouts, but after the text gets to this point (in length) the slide (when printed) will SHRINK the text to fit. I'd prefer if the overflow text would go onto a new page. So that when it prints I have one page with the slide at the top and then notes beneath and then the rest of the notes print on the additional pages.

Can this be done? If so, how?

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe there is a way to overflow the text. Your easiest bet is to make do with the smaller text size. Another alternative (which may require more work but could lead to a nicer design) would be to export a PDF of just the slides, then use Pages/Acrobat/Word/etc to build a document with both the text and slides by hand.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of AppleScripts / Automator Actions around that will extract the text from the Presenter notes, so that you can easily create a Pages/Word document to act as handouts.

You can also export your slides as images to add to the pages/word doc.

See:

http://www.hyperorg.com/blogger/2010/07/07/extracting-speakers-notes-from-keynote/
An automator action from David Weinberger to extract speakers notes.

http://www.tuaw.com/2012/12/10/send-keynote-presenter-notes-to-evernote-with-applescript/
Sending Keynote presenter notes to Evernote with AppleScript.

and http://humbledown.org/keynote_speakers_notes.xhtml

> an XSLT stylesheet that you pass your Keynote presentation to, and it outputs an XHTML document with the titles and thumbnails of each slide along with the speakers notes

I have not tested these yet!

Comment: The XSLT stylesheet is not available on the linked website anymore, as the domain is now vacant. I was able to retrieve it from the Internet Archive, though  :)  -> https://web.archive.org/web/*/humbledown.org/files/keynote-speakers-notes-xhtml.xslt

Answer (score 0):

You can control the size of the text in the speaker's notes. Pulling back to a 12 point font will greatly increase how much text displays.

But if, even at 12 points, you have multiple pages of notes for the slide, your best bet maybe to insert text pages into the handout.

Answer (score 0):

A simple workaround is to duplicate the slide and split the speaker notes across the two (or more). If you have no transitions between slides, no one in the audience will know that you clicked between them.